# How to rerun the failed pipeline in azure data factory(i want only run failed activity)

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am running a pipeline where im looping through all the excel files into azure sql, but i have one failed excel sheet in the pipeline, remaing files are succssfully, i want rerun the failes sheet.

Comment: could you please provide the error what you have got?

Comment: It depends on the way you are looping through the files and the error you are receiving, but you could probably set a retry amount of the activity you're using. Could you please provide further details?

Comment: @Chinnu, if its just one activity inside the pipeline that you want to run , you can deactivate other activities in the pipeline and run the pipeline again

Answer (score 1):

If you go into the failed run under 'Monitoring', the 'Rerun' button has a down-arrow, when you click this you can choose 'Rerun from failed activity'. This will rerun the failed activity and potential following activities that have not been run. The activites that succeeded previously will be skipped.